# JVM Memory Allocation Failures - graph shows unique stair step pattern

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory

Our Web Application uses IBM Websphere.  There is daily activity, but at night none and garbage collection collect back down to the normal low line through out the days. No indication of memory leak problems in the GC graph's pattern.

We are trying to understand the JVM Heap memory graph that shows a doubling Stair Step pattern of Memory Allocation Failures (MAFs) over the course of 6 days.

MAFs day 1 are at 0.5mb and stays at that level until it jumps to 1mb the next day -stays at that level and then 2mb, then 4mb then 8mb, then finally 16mb and the JVM will then restart at some point automatically.  Truly Doubling each time.

What would cause that unique pattern of stair steps for the memory allocation failures graph?

We normally have only seen a straight line across on the Memory Allocation Failure on the Object Sizes graph.

Answer (score 0):

My thought is that you have data structures that have long-lived references to them.  For example, a value that is tied to a map key will not be gc'd if the key is not dereferenced.  Likewise,  if you are using an object as a key and not explicitly removing that key from the map, then the key and its value will never be out of scope, as long as that map lives.  If you have a situation where the key should be automatically dereferenced when the value is set to null, use a weakhashmap instead.

If you don't believe a map to be a problem, there may be a bunch of other reasons, like a jdbc connections that are never closed, static objects that accumulate state over time, objects created and associated with a long-lived object that is never deleted, etc.  To find the answer, use the visualVM tool to look at what's consuming all your memory.  For sure, though, the problem is caused by a memory leak in your code.